# closing wpf window from within frame

Tags: wpf, vb.net, navigation

I'm porting a Winform project to WPF and started working with Windows & Pages (using the frame control). Basically my intention is to navigate from one page to the next until the user logs in successfully. Now since the logIn is handled at the Page level... my question is:

**How can the Page Shut Down the Parent Window?!?**

Thanks in advance if you know the code in vb. If not I'll figure it out in C#.

```
Public Sub CloseLogIn()
    Dim LogIn = TryCast(Me.Parent, Window)
    If LogIn IsNot Nothing Then
        LogIn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by _Shut Down the Parent Window_? Do you want to close it? Or do you want to exit the application?

Comment: sorry. just close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Public Sub CloseLogIn()
    Dim LogIn = Window.GetWindow(Me)
    If LogIn IsNot Nothing Then
        LogIn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

The [Window.GetWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.getwindow%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method returns a reference to the Window object that hosts the content tree within which the dependency object is located.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the Window that hosts the [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611620%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) by using the property Parent on the Page instance.

The property is of type `DependencyObject`, so you have to cast the value to the type you need. In you case you cast it to `Window`.

```
public class MyPage : Page{

   public void CloseWindow(){
     var parentWindow = this.Parent as Window;

     if (parentWindow != null) {
       parentWindow.Close();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jehof, I think your on the right track but just tried the code and This.Parent is comming up empty (nothing).

Comment: @user1603568 Is `this.Parent` really nothing or is the variable `parentWindow` after the cast per `as` nothing

Comment: Dim LogIn = TryCast(Me.Parent, Window), this is what I did in vb.net. Basically in the TryCast the Me.Parent comes up as nothing. So obviously the variable LogIn is the same.

Comment: @user1603568 i think you should add more code to get a answer to your question.

Comment: Public Sub CloseLogIn()
        Dim LogIn = TryCast(Me.Parent, Window)

        If LogIn IsNot Nothing Then
            LogIn.Close()
        End If
    End Sub